How can I compare the current analysis with an analysis loaded from a baseline n days ago with NDepend
I would like to compare two NDepend analyses:

The last recent analysis
An analysis from a baseline created n days ago, eg. 15 days

Here is my code so far (its X# not C# so the syntax is a little different):
VAR ndProject := ndManager.LoadProject(ndprojPath)
LOCAL analysisResultRef AS IAnalysisResultRef
ndProject:BaselineDuringAnalysis:AnalysisResultMode := BaselineAnalysisResultMode.NDaysAgoAnalysisResult
ndProject:BaselineDuringAnalysis:AnalysisResultCreatedNDaysAgo := 15
VAR result := ndProject:TryGetMostRecentAnalysisResultRef(OUT analysisResultRef)
VAR refDate1 := analysisResultRef:Date
Console.WriteLine(i"Date1: {refDate1}")

Currently I am getting the most recent analysis.
My question is how do I load the analysis based on the baseline 15 days ago?
Since TryGetMostRecentAnalysisResultRef loads the most recent analysis, I have not found the equivalent for loading an analysis other than the most recent one or the one based on the UI settings in the NDepend documentation.

The only way to load a specific analysis I have found so far is to enumerate through all available AnalysisResultsRefs for the project, compare the date and load the one you want:
VAR AnalysisResultRefs := ndProject:GetAvailableAnalysisResultsRefs()
FOREACH resultRef AS IAnalysisResultRef IN AnalysisResultRefs
  VAR daysAgo := (Int)(DateTime.Now - resultRef.Date).TotalDays
  Console.WriteLine(i"Date: {resultRef.Date} {daysAgo} days ago")
  IF daysAgo == 15
     LOCAL analysis15 := resultRef:Load() AS IAnalysisResult
     LOCAL issues := analysis15:ComputeIssues() As IIssuesSet 
     Console.WriteLine(i"Issues computed with {issues.AllIssuesCount} Issues")
  END IF
NEXT


yes this is the right way
